# Angular : Perfoming successive HTTP-Delete in a loop doesn't work

Tags: angular, crud, angular2-observables, http-delete

I'm developing a website with Angular CRUD operations, but I struggle to perform successive delete on my database.

I recover my IDs which need to be deleted from my database in an array called **« this.checkedLogs »** (this part does work). 
Then, when I click on a button I call a function which used to perform these deletes : **« onModalConfirm »**. 
The problem is that it goes so fast that my iterator doesn’t have the time to change its value and the actual ID to be delete from my array that the function has already loop. 
Moreover, at the end of the loop the condition **« if (this.checkedLogs.length == 0) »** isn’t true which show that it goes so fast.

I was thinking of adding wait functions, but I don’t know if this fits into good practices.
I’m still a beginner in Angular and I’m not yet comfortable with everything around Observable.

- Here is my service.ts :

```
deleteLogsByID(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.delete(`${API_BASE_URL}/delete/id/${id}`, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

- Here my component.ts :

```
deleteLogsByID(id: number): void {
        this.logsSubscription = this.LogsService.deleteLogsByID(id).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.deleteMessage = data;
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.showSpinner = false;
                this.error = error.message;
                this.showError = true;
            }
        );
    }

onModalConfirm() {
        /** Getting the length of my array by updating this.selectionAmount */
        this.updateSelectionAmount();

        /** If it’s not empty */
        if (this.selectionAmount != 0) {

            let iterator = this.checkedLogs.values();
            for (let index = 0; index < this.selectionAmount; index++) {
                /** Getting the id of the iterator */
                let id: number = iterator.next().value;

                /** Calling my delete function */
                this.deleteLogsByID(id);


                /** Removing the id from the array */
                this.checkedLogs.splice(id, 1);
            }

            /** When everything is done, reload the page */
            if (this.checkedLogs.length == 0)
                window.location.reload()
        }
    }

updateSelectionAmount() {
        this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
    }
```

- The html code doesn’t seem to be important in my problem but here is my backend code of my delete function (which works fine) :

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Delete a logs by its id", produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
@DeleteMapping("/delete/id/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteLogsById(@PathVariable Integer id) {

    Integer idRemoved = logsService.deleteLogsById(id);

    if (idRemoved == 0)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    String responseReturn = "Logs removed with id " + id;

    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseReturn, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible for you to expand your back-end to be able to handle accepting a collection of Ids as well as singular Ids? This would likely be a bit more robust and not incur as many network requests.

Comment: I see what you mean, it could be an great option ! If I'm understanding you correctly, I need to create a new endpoint which will perform multiple delete by passing the array into the body of the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you have right, for loop is executed to fast, it calls bunch of request, and checkedLogs is spliced before request are executed. Don't know all yours app logic, but I would suggest to use good old callbacks to make delete operation kind of sequential. onModalConfirm would be something like:

```
onModalConfirm() {
    /** Getting the length of my array by updating this.selectionAmount */
    this.updateSelectionAmount();

    /** If it’s not empty */
    if (this.selectionAmount != 0) {
        let iterator = this.checkedLogs.values();
        const callDelete = () => {
            let id: number = iterator.next().value;
            const continueFn = (id) => {
                if (id !== undefined) {
                    callDelete();
                }
            }
            if (id !== undefined) {
                this.deleteLogsByID(id, continueFn);
            }
        }
        callDelete();
    }
}
```

and deleteLogsByID would be:

```
deleteLogsByID(id: number, callbackFn: (id: number) => void): void {
    this.logsSubscription = this.LogsService.deleteLogsByID(id).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
            this.deleteMessage = data;
            callbackFn(id)
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.showSpinner = false;
            this.error = error.message;
            this.showError = true;
            callbackFn(id);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @MRsa, thank you for your response ! I understand the logic with the callback but I'm not familiar with this syntaxis : "const callDelete=()=> {...}" I'll search about that. Moreover I tested the code you wrote and it seems that the deletelogsByID(...) is called twice more than it should. But as I'm not familiar with the syntax i'm not able to solve it

Comment: const fnName = () =>{} are almost same as (only binding this is different)
const fnName = function () {}
Anyway I think that problem where in array.splice - params are wrong (first param should be start postiton not Id value)
I changed answer, just check does your iterator on end of loop returns "undefined" or something else and change in code. It's a bad idea to have iterator that loops across array thas is also changed in a same function (splice)